# Security Patches for Ubuntu 16 after 9 Months

Tags: 16.04, updates

I have installed Ubuntu 16 on my machine. I have come to know that after 9 months security patches will not be available.

Please let me know how can I get support after 9 months. Is there any way I could purchase the support?

Regards,
Jatinder

Comment: As Stormlord pointed out, Ubuntu 16.04 is an LTS (Long Term Support) release. It will receive security updates through April 2021.

Comment: Whoever has told you is a ... well, That is 100% a lie

Comment: Only non-LTS releases get 9 months of support and patches.  LTS releases get far longer support (through April 2021)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean?  16.04 is an LTS release.  This means that you'll get full support and updates for 5 years.